# change the layout of the alertdialog multi choice items

Tags: android, android-layout, android-alertdialog

i have a dialog fragment where i get the user's choices via the setmultiplechoiceitems (i persist the selected items + pass them to the host activity via an interface).

I'm now trying to use a custom layout for the alertdialog and I wanted to know what is the best way to use my checkbox layout instead of the default one (since i've already spent too much time getting the first code to work, i really don't want to start all over again with a listener for each checkbox, sharefprefs and stuff...) I want to know if i can use my custom checkbox with my actual code.

as you can see in the screenshot, i already added my custom layout (the bottom checklist) using `.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_settings,null))`
 but the selected items are not persistent.

[image]

here is my code :

```
public class TimelineSettings extends DialogFragment {
ArrayList<Integer> selected_categories = new ArrayList<Integer>();
boolean[] itemsChecked = {false, false, false, false, false, false};


public interface dialoglistener {
    public void onOkay(ArrayList<Integer> selected);
    public void onCancel();
}
dialoglistener mlistener;

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    // ensure that the host activity implements the callback interface
    try {
        // Instantiate the dialogListener so we can send events to the host
        mlistener = (dialoglistener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        // if activity doesn't implement the interface, throw an exception
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement dialogListener");
    }
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    for(int i=0;i<itemsChecked.length;i++){
        if(selected_categories.contains((String)String.valueOf(i)))
            itemsChecked[i]=true;
    }
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    // Set the dialog title
    builder.setTitle("Choisissez vos paramètres")
            .setMultiChoiceItems(R.array.categories, itemsChecked,
                    new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int indexselected,
                                            boolean isChecked) {
                            if (isChecked) {
                                // If the user checked the item, add it to the selected items
                                if(!selected_categories.contains(indexselected)){
                                    selected_categories.add(indexselected);
                                    itemsChecked[indexselected]=true;
                                }
                            } else if (selected_categories.contains(indexselected)) {
                                // Else, if the item is already in the array, remove it
                                selected_categories.remove(indexselected);
                                itemsChecked[indexselected]=false;
                            }
                        }
                    })
            .setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_settings,null))
                    // Set the action buttons
            .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    mlistener.onOkay(selected_categories);
                }


            })
            .setNegativeButton("Annuler", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    mlistener.onCancel();
                }
            });
    //this part is to customize the look of the alertdialog :
    Dialog d = builder.show();
    int dividerId = d.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/titleDivider", null, null);
    int textViewId = d.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/alertTitle", null, null);
    Typeface roboto = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(),"fonts/Roboto-Thin.ttf");
    View divider = d.findViewById(dividerId);
    divider.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.main_green));
    TextView tv = (TextView) d.findViewById(textViewId);
    tv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.main_green));
    tv.setTypeface(roboto);
    return d; //was : return builder.create();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `selected_categories` is an ArrayList of Integer objects, but when you check the contents you are checking for a String using `selected_categories.contains((String)String.valueOf(i))`
You are not going to find any Strings in your Integer ArrayList, so this statement will always return false.

Try:

```
for(int i=0;i<itemsChecked.length;i++){
        if(selected_categories.contains(Integer.valueOf(i)) {
            itemsChecked[i]=true;
    }
}
```

Comment: when you say "when you check the conten..." are you talking about the deafault checklist, or my custom checklist, because that code works fine with the default one. What i'm trying to do is to use the functions and parameters i have in `.setmultichoiceitems`but with my custom layout. is that possible ?